reference to packed field is unaligned
I'm tyring to Upgrade a anchor program from 0.25.0 to 0.30.1 version. I'm getting this error on the structs
error[E0793]: reference to packed field is unaligned
   --> programs/nodestore/src/lib.rs:302:15
    |
302 |         addel(&mut nds.pset, trf_purch_no);
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: packed structs are only aligned by one byte, and many modern architectures penalize unaligned field accesses
    = note: creating a misaligned reference is undefined behavior (even if that reference is never dereferenced)
    = help: copy the field contents to a local variable, or replace the reference with a raw pointer and use `read_unaligned`/`write_unaligned` (loads and stores via `*p` must be properly aligned even when using raw pointers)


Is there a safe to to upgrade this program , Not break the current existing PDAs . All the structs have zero_copy implemented on them.

The struct were only zero_copy, they were not following repr(C), So  there might have been some alignment issues with newer anchor version.
I had two options, One was Using this method down here, Assigning to a new variable and then reassign after modification.
  let mut fset = fnds.fset;
  addfel( &mut fset, acc.next_purch_no - fpch.first_fnd_purch_no);
  fnds.fset = fset;

            OR 

By using read_unaligned and write_unaligned functions like this
use std::ptr;

// Unsafe block because we're working with raw pointers
unsafe {
    // Create a raw pointer to the field
    let pset_ptr = &nds.pset as *const _;

    // Read unaligned data safely
    let mut pset = ptr::read_unaligned(pset_ptr);

    // Use the field as needed
    addel(&mut pset, trf_purch_no);

    // Write back to the original packed field
    let pset_ptr_mut = &mut nds.pset as *mut _;
    ptr::write_unaligned(pset_ptr_mut, pset);
}

Better then using some unsafe methods i decided to use the first one which is simple.
Note : This issue only happens when i try to pass some struct field as reference.

Oh cool thanks. Could you explain a bit the solution? Is that because of the new bytemuck version? Or because of another build target that as a different alignment? Are the zero copy struct all repr(C) or packed?

Just Updated My answer @JonasH.

Oh awesome! Thanks so much :)
